# Unsure about example given on BrowserSync homepage

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync

Consider this [example](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/#gulp-reload) given on the BrowserSync + Gulp page regarding `Browser Reloading`, especially this part:

```
// use default task to launch BrowserSync and watch JS files
gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync'], function () {

    // add browserSync.reload to the tasks array to make
    // all browsers reload after tasks are complete.
    gulp.watch("js/*.js", ['js', browserSync.reload]);
});
```

As task dependencies are run asynchronously (here: the `js` and browserSync.reload) couldn't it happen that the reload finishes before the `js` task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, according to the documentation, that's a possibility.

Off that same page...

```
 (make sure you return the stream from your tasks to ensure the browser is reloaded at the correct time)
```

If it's an async task it will just fire and not return anything, and the watcher will not know to refresh.  Or it may reload before the process is done.

To get around this, you should be adding callbacks to your tasks.

```
gulp.task('somename', function() {
  var stream = gulp.src('client/**/*.js')
    .pipe(minify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
  return stream;
});
```

Just return the stream so Gulp knows what is up.  Then set the watch for the task you want:

```
gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync'], function () {
  // Watched tasks are run in parallel, not in series.
  gulp.watch(['*.js'], ['somename', browserSync.reload]);
});
```

This is all included in the documentation:

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support